# stream textfile to textbox c#

Tags: c#, textbox

Suppose i have a textfile which continuous to be updated with text, how can i display the contents in a textbox in windows form (in real-time)?

for example. this is the contents of log.txt:

```
connected, bla bla bla
disconnected, bla bla bla
```

PS: i want it to be displayed in textBox of Form1 (real time also) so everytime the text file has new text, the textbox displays it. Any ideas, pls help. thanks.  also can u provide a sample working code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Use the example on MSDN (see the link above) you can add a event handler to `Changed` Event
and update your textbox from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Application.DoEvents();` once you've updated your text. But note that updating too often might cause flicker as well as slow down your overall processing. Also note that this is error prone if any drawing/update code causes updates/draws again (infinite recursion).

Edit: Read half the question ...
Add a `FileSystemWatcher` to watch for changes to the log file. However this is a very ineffective approach and depending on the settings used to write the log file you might be missing access rights and/or the file might update only when the application closes. If both processes are your own code and you're able to modify them, you should think about other possibilities (e.g. a simple "server" you can connect to using some telnet (or custom) client).

Answer (score 0):

Insert a RichTextBox and a FilesystemWatcher, and a textbox or something else to store the path and filename of the text file you want to show. Now, go to the FilesystemWatcher_Changed (or whatever it's called) event. There you put an if that checks if the changed file is the one you want to be shown, and then `RichTextBox.LoadFile(file)`.
What this is going to do is monitor the fileystsem (hard disk or any folder you specify), and every time a file has cha nged, it's going to check if it's the file that we're looking at. If it is, it's going to reload the file into the RichTextBox.
Don't forget to set the RaiseEvent and Path properties of the FilesystemWatcher.

**Example:**

```
string blaFile = "C:\TextFile.txt"; // The text file that we want to read.

private void FilesystemWatcher_Changed(....).... // The FilesystemWatcher_Changed event notifies us when a file on the monitored path (FilesystemWatcher.Path) has changed. When a file has changed the code within this event gets executed.
{
    if (e.File == blaFile) // We check if the file that has chenged, is the one we want.
    {
        RichTextBox.LoadFile(blaFile); // It is! We load it into the RichtextBox again so that it's "up-to-date"!
    }
}
```

I'm not completely sure about the `e.File` as I haven't used C# in a while now, but it's something like that.

Comment: A RTF control might be a bit overkill for this. Don't think it's worth the overhead just to save writing some file loading code.

Comment: You could use the ReadFile function, or whatever it was called. But I just thought a RichtextBox would be easier for this purpose :p

Comment: what will i put in the if statement? i dont get it. sorry

Comment: also robin j, how can i make the richtextbox show the latest stream? so i do not have to scroll down to see the latest text. tnx

Comment: ... The latest stream? You mean it should automatically scroll to the lowest point? That's be something like this: `RichTextBox.SelectionStart = RichTextBox.Text.Length;
RichTextBox.ScrollToCaret();`

Answer (score -1):

It is not suggested to use text file, since there are two processes to access the file and you require real-time update.

Try to use NamePipeServerStream and NamePipeClientStream for two processes memory sharing.